# Sql Server, OPENJSON sql:identity() parse problems

Tags: sql-server-2019, json

I'm starting to work with the JSON operators in Sql Server 2019, and on an msdn page, I found a chunk talking about the $.sql:identity() operator and how that's supposed to give you an integer index into the json array you're processing.

The problem is that the example on the msdn page doesn't work.

This is the code from [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
DECLARE @array VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @array = '[{"month":"Jan", "temp":10},{"month":"Feb", "temp":12},{"month":"Mar", "temp":15},
           {"month":"Apr", "temp":17},{"month":"May", "temp":23},{"month":"Jun", "temp":27}
          ]';

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@array)
    WITH (  month VARCHAR(3),
            temp int,
            month_id tinyint '$.sql:identity()') as months
```

but when I try to run it, I get a parsing exception:

```
JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character ':' is found at position 5.
```

Any clues?  Is there a working way to get the array index in a json array as you go through it?

Thanks

Comment: The doc page you referred to mentions Azure Synapse Analytics for the identity array element. I don't believe it applies to other SQL flavors.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, but the page also says SQL Server 2016+

Comment: @user1664043 The general document regarding `OPENJSON()` supports SQL Server 2016+ but that specific section regarding array element identity specifically states at the end of it: "*The identity is available only in the serverless SQL pool in Synapse Analytics.*" Therefore array element identity is not available in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

The right solution to your problem is:

```sql
DECLARE @array VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @array = '[{"month":"Jan", "temp":10},{"month":"Feb", "temp":12},{"month":"Mar", "temp":15},
               {"month":"Apr", "temp":17},{"month":"May", "temp":23},{"month":"Jun", "temp":27}]';

SELECT months.*, A.[key] month_id FROM OPENJSON(@array) A
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.value)
        WITH (  month VARCHAR(3),
                temp int) as months
```

Comment: thanks this saved my bacon :)